How to define trace widths for KiCAD's freerouting/autorouter
I am pretty new to kicad, and hope i can find some advice here? (I could share the kicad example schematics too, if needed)
I am having a this example schematics.
Here you see a power supply for 2 modules and one path for a high current path via resistor R2 (2.2Ω / 1.5A)
The R2 shall be at least with 1mm trace width from J1 to R2 and from R2 to GND and the GND to J1 again

The modules itself shall be with 0.2mm trace width to be able to connect them properly.
But whatever I tried I did not manage to configure it to have a clean trace width of 1mm from J1 to R2 and back. And that the trace width to the modules is using 0.2mm
I have found this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/93178/386022
But I could not reproduce it. Neither assigning to the pins (J1 and R2) nor assigning the connection lines to net classes worked.

Why are you not using a ground plane for that connection? Are you experienced with any PCB layout tools other than KiCAD?

Is the question "how a PCB should be designed regardless of the tool used" or "how to make KiCad do what I want even if it is not how it should be done"? Your schematic also won't work if you are using SPI without chip selects, so it may not be useful to work on the PCB at all at this stage.

I recommend utilizing the KiCad getting started guide:
https://docs.kicad.org/8.0/en/getting_started_in_kicad/getting_started_in_kicad.html
In particular the part about "net classes".

@Andyaka ground plane would be also an option for the specific case. But the question was ment to be more specific on how to control the trace widths for cases like shown.
So the other case, how to define the width for the 3.3V is would be still open

@Justme thank you for your info, the schematics may not work from electrical point, but the question is how to define trace widths for autorouting? So the issue is not the bus lines, neither the logical wireing, only the question: how to tell freerouting how to define the trace widths

@S_G can you pinpoint me specifically the section how to configure autorouting to define custom widths? I have defined the net-classes but it is not calculating it properly

@cilap since I never use autorouting (it's unreliable and doesn't give a damn about good routing practice), I can't help you with the autorouter.
What you can do is manually route the "big" lines and then let the thing do the rest.
Or you do it yourself. Properly :)

I am just chiming in to say that autorouting is going to take more time to setup than the time you will save on anything short of a 200sqcm+ 12L+ board. I have designed several square meters of boards in the past 10 years, we used autorouting once as we were in a time crunch, and it was awful.
